# React Component won't render new state even after rerender

Tags: reactjs, components, state

Basically I am having an issue where a react component will not render an array that comes from its state. The state does contain the array I want and the render method is called again when the array var is filled, but nothing shows up.

I have tried prefilling the state array with dummy data and it renders just fine. But when I use a function to fill the array, the page updates and nothing shows. If I inspect the state of the component it has the data that I want but the render method of the component seems to not want to display it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withAuthorization } from '../Session';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'; //
import 'firebase/firestore';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <p>Signed in users only</p>
    <hr />

    <h1>Available Scopes</h1>
    <ScopeRender />

  </div>
);


class ScopeRenderBase extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scopes: []
        }
        //this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getScopes();
        //console.log(this.state.scopes);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        //console.log(this.state.scopes);
    }

    getScopes() {
        let tempScopes = [];
        this.props.firebase.db.collection("scopes").where("status", "==", 1).get()
            .then( (querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    tempScopes.push(doc.data().address);
                })
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });

        //console.log(tempScopes);
        this.setState({ 
            scopes: tempScopes
        });
    }

    render() {
        const displayPosts = this.state.scopes.map((scope, index) =>
            <li key={index}>{scope}</li>
        );
        console.log(this.state.scopes);
        return(
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.scopes}</div>
                <ul>{displayPosts}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const ScopeRender = withFirebase(ScopeRenderBase);

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(condition)(Home);
export { ScopeRender };
```

With this code the state contains the data (scopes) I want after the function getScopes() is called, but the render method does not show the data.

If I prefill the data with dummy chars and comment out getScopes() in componentDidMount() like below and keep everything else the same, the dummy chars display just fine.

```
class ScopeRenderBase extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scopes: ['a','b','c']
        }
        //this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        //await this.getScopes();
        //console.log(this.state.scopes);
    }
```

I expect the code to display a bulleted list of the array coming from the components state after getScopes() is called as soon as the component mounts, but instead nothing shoes. I have confirmed though through dev tools that the data does exist in the scopes state array, render doesn't show it though.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `getScopes`, you are filling `tempScopes` in a `then` of a Promise, which is run *asynchronously*.
But below it you are also calling `setState` immediately, which means at the time you call `setState`, `tempScopes` array is still empty. 
You should move call to `setState` also inside `then`. Something like this:

```
       .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                tempScopes.push(doc.data().address);
            })
            this.setState({scopes:tempScopes});
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

As in usual fashion, the answer came to me moments after posting. I think the issues stemmed from the binding of this within the getScopes function. This code fixed the issue.

```
getScopes() {
    let tempScopes = [];
    this.props.firebase.db.collection("scopes").where("status", "==", 1).get()
        .then( (querySnapshot) => (
            querySnapshot.forEach( (doc) => (
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    scopes: [ ...this.state.scopes, doc.data().address ]
                }))
            ))
        ))
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
}
```